# Lazarus ListBox SaveToFile File Name with special characters

Tags: windows, filesystems, filenames, lazarus

I'm writing an application with Lazarus (1.5) fpc (3.1.1) targeting Windows XP/7/10. 
My Application read and write files in filesystem in some path choosed by users.  If path or filename contain special chars (like à è é) for example:

C:\Users\DeAndrè\out.txt

Application raise the exception:

> 'EFCreateError' Unable to create file "C:\Users\DeAndrè\out.txt".

Is possible to reproduce this issue writing a simple application with a sigle form: 
Drag into the form a TListBox (ListBox1), two TButton (Button1 and Button2) and a TSaveDialog (SaveDialog1).

In the OnClick event of Button1 (used only to write some data on ListBox1):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Simple Add Hello to ListBox
  ListBox1.Items.Add('Hello '+IntToStr(ListBox1.Items.Count));
end;
```

In OnClick event of Button2:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName);
  end;
end;
```

Run the application and click "Button1" some times (just for add some words in the List) then click on Button2 and try to save content to a path containing special characters...

I have noticed that if I convert FileName with function UTF8ToAnsi it work, but why? Windows FileSystem isn't UTF8?

There is "standard" a solution? for example setting the application to use filesystem in correct mode or similar?

Thank you

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thank you, my Windows installations use NTFS FileSystem, according to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748(v=vs.85).aspx) is Unicode

Comment: Is the lazarus code calling the Unicode API

Comment: @David same sample code in Delphi (XE8) work without error...

Comment: Yes. But that's not really the point. Does the lazarus code use the Unicode API.

Comment: Sorry, the comment was not finished. Forget about it. And I bet that Lazarus (by default) uses the ANSI APIs, not the Unicode APIs. Delphi XE8 uses UnicodeString by default, while Lazarus uses (old style) AnsiString by default, AFAIK.

Comment: In fact.. there is an additional "Custom Option" to add to compiler to set UnicodeAPI: `EnableUTF8RTL`, thank @Rudy and @David

Comment: The Windows API actually either uses ANSI or UTF-16, not UTF-8. I guess there is an option to use UTF-16 too, at least on Windows. But then the APIs called must be UTF-16 too, by default. Otherwise, you will still need  conversions for each API call.

Comment: @Rudy The Lazarus libraries could convert from UTF8 to UTF16 before calling any API. That would be perfectly reasonable.

Comment: As I said: you would need conversions for each API call. But I doubt that happens. I did not look at the sources (yet), but it would surprise me. I assume they usually use the Ansi APIs. That would explain what was said in the question.

Comment: @rudy Apparently that's exactly what happens. It's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @David: I never said it wasn't reasonable. <g>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the directions of Rudy and David I found the solution: 
To enable Lazarus to use UnicodeAPI you must add **-dEnableUTF8RTL** on "Custom Option":

On "Project"->"Project Options"->"Additions and Override"

Click on "Add"->"Custom Option" and Add

```
-dEnableUTF8RTL
```

This force compiler to use Unicode for FileSystem Access.

Is also possible to click on button "Set UTF8 in RTL".
This button in addition to -dEnableUTF8RTL adds the option:

```
-FcUTF8
```

In this link of Lazarus Forum: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=27240.0 
there is an extract from the "Wiki" page about Lazarus and UTF8:

> Usually the RTL uses the system codepage for strings (e.g. FileExists
>   and TStringList.LoadFromFile). On Windows this is a non Unicode
>   encoding, so you can only use characters from your language group. The
>   LCL works with UTF-8 encoding, which is the full Unicode range. On
>   Linux and Mac OS X UTF-8 is typically the system codepage, so the RTL
>   uses here by default CP_UTF8.
>
> Since FPC 2.7.1 the default system codepage of the RTL can be changed
>   to UTF-8 (CP_UTF8). So Windows users can now use UTF-8 strings in the
>   RTL.

Comment: You can accept your own answer (two days after you post it), which will help others in future,